# Securing Laravel application code

Tags: laravel, security

Im installing my Laravel projects in the servers of the clients to use in Local Networks.. can you ofuscate the code or protect it with tools like Homestead / Vagrant or something like that ?? Or only at the Windows user levels I can protect the code from being stolen..

Answer (score 0):

If your applications run on local networks you don't really need to protect something because your app can't be call from internet.

You could use a proxy access from the local network but i'm not sure if it's really useful.

Best

Comment: I want to protect the code/Laravel folder from the people accesing the local server trough local pc or in the same LAN... no from the internet.. 

Anybody can access the wamp folder and copy all the files..